# FFT - manipulating phase spectrum information

Tags: signal-processing, fft, spectrum, phase

I wonder if there is any use of phase spectrum, or we use amplitude information for all the tasks avaliable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question at all, but maybe a signal processing question. However, minimal research into what the FFT is would've shown that no, just observing the amplitude information throws away half of the information in a signal.

Comment: Phase defines [delay of each frequency component](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_information_is_contained_in_the_phase_spectrum_of_a_signal2), so this is a measure of signal shape

Comment: @MarcusMüller "However, minimal research into what the FFT is would've shown that no, just observing the amplitude information throws away half of the information in a signal." For the record, it is much more complicated than that. But I have to agree : this question does belong to [dsp.stackexchange.com/](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can't reconstruct or filter a signal without the phase spectrum in addition to the amplitude information.